# Internal drive on MacBook won't appear on desktop

Tags: snow-leopard, hard-drive, desktop

Why doesn't internal drive appear on desktop after a fresh install of Snow Leopard 10.6.8?

Answer (score 6):

Since Snow Leopard the hard drives aren't shown on the Desktop by default. However if you upgraded from Leopard or earlier it does honor the original settings. However, some updates will disable this setting during the upgrade.

Have a look under `Finder` preferences and make sure the `Hard Disk` box is ticked.

[image: Finder Preferences]

Comment: This is good, on the assumption that it does show in the finder elsewhere and as such is proven to mount, then it's almost certainly your answer.